# How to tilt inner element forward when tilting outer back with css 3d transforms

Tags: css, 3d, css-transforms

I would like to get an effect of an outer element tilting back along the z axis and an inner element standing up out of it in a normal 2d perspective. In other words given this html

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

I would like the outer element to tilt backwards with its side lines approaching a vanishing point while the inner element's sides are vertical.

How do I achieve this? Using the css

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
#outer {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(45deg)
}

#inner {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: tomato;
  background-image: url(http://www.w3schools.com/html/smiley.gif);
  background-size: 100%;    
}
```

I thought I could just do

```
#inner {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-45deg);
}
```

but that just makes it tilt more.
[Here is a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/runuti/2/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set preserve 3d

```
#outer {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#inner {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: tomato;
  background-image: url(http://www.w3schools.com/html/smiley.gif);
  background-size: 100%;   
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
}
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bikoxete/1/)

Comment: I might have oversimplified my question. In reality [I'm using svg and an svg image element](http://jsbin.com/viwak/3/). For this `preserve-3d` doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: I guess that it isn't supported in SVG, but I don't know for sure. Maybe you can make the parent container standard HTML, and only the child in SVG ? May be it will work then.