# 3d transform perspective in svg

Tags: css, svg, 3d, css-transforms

I'm creating a simple html and svg videogame.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23374997/5056) I asked about how to do nested elements where the outer one is tilted backwards around the x axis, and the inner one is tilted forward.

[image: nested 3d tilting]

[To my surprise the solution doesn't work for svg.](http://jsbin.com/viwak/4/edit?html,css,output). Why and is there some other way to achieve this effect?

Comment: I think you'd have to use SVG's built in transform which [doesn't have great support](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20tr). This is because CSS selectors cannot very well select the inner SVG elements (because they're similar to elements being painted)

Comment: `svg #id` works. You can check on the jsbin, it sleects just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG has no support for 3D transforms.  You can transform the whole SVG (the browser renders it to an image first) but not the individual elements.

```
  <div id="outer">
    <svg id="inner" width="500" height="500">
      <image x="20" y="90" width="200" height="200" xlink:href='http://www.w3schools.com/html/smiley.gif' />
    </svg>
  </div>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/DCqUp/)

Comment: Yeah but then I can't use d3 to animate elements in the same svg document...

Comment: I think that should still work.  The SVG will be re-rendered and transformed.

Answer (score 0):

The document at http://cs.sru.edu/~ddailey/svg/XYZrot3D2.svg uses separate 3D transforms for different things within one SVG. It's not working properly in Chrome, but it is in FF.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I think the bigger issue is that as far as I can tell, this doesn't address the question asked about nesting elements and tilting them in opposite directions. Unless I maybe missed something?